# Combining rows based on duplicate values in two columns

Tags: powerquery

I have a part of the table, where columns are connected to each others with codes. There can be multiple connection, but not always:

```
A   B
9910    9905
5595    5590
5636    5595
5716    5636
1116    1109
3737    3734
3750    3737
9112    9107
2014    1993
2061    2014
2144    2061
2633    2628
1786    1781
5800    5595
```

Some of the B values are start points and some of the A values are end points in line of codes.
I want to create table where codes are connected to each others as follow, based on amount of connecting codes:

```
9905    9910        
5590    5595    5636    5716
1109    1116        
3734    3737    3750    
9107    9112        
1993    2014    2061    2144
2628    2633        
1781    1786        
5595    5800
```

How to do this with power query? Thank you in advance.

I tried following, but it did not work:

1. Sorted values in column A and B,
2. Changed data type to number, and
3. used following function:

```
let
    FindConnectedCodes = (table as table, code as number) as any =>
    let
        FilteredTable = Table.SelectRows(table, each [A] = code or [B] = code),
        NextCodes = List.Transform(FilteredTable[A], each if _ = code then [B] else _),
        Result = if List.IsEmpty(NextCodes) then {code} else {code} & @FindConnectedCodes(Table.RemoveRows(FilteredTable, 0), List.First(NextCodes))
    in
        Result
in
    FindConnectedCodes
```

And,
4. created custom column: = FindConnectedCodes(#"Sorted Rows",[A]).

I get errors, expecially in nextCodes line.

Comment: I try to create a FilteredTable, where value is selected by column A or B value bases on code (1st set of codes from column A). NextCodes should create next set of codes to be checked in the recursion. Result should check, is there still codes to be checked. This should produce a list of connected codes.

Comment: 5800 is end point (like different product), which is using 5595 as well as a source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this which does not need recursion

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if List.ContainsAny(
    List.RemoveNulls({
    try Source[Column1]{[Index]-1} otherwise null,
    try Source[Column2]{[Index]-1} otherwise null})
    ,{[Column1],[Column2]}) then null else [Index]),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {{"data", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct(_[Column2]&_[Column1]),"|"), type text}}),
Names=List.Transform({1 .. List.Max(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows"[data], each List.Count(Text.Split(_,"|"))))}, each "Column"& Text.From(_)),
split = Table.SplitColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), Names),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(split,{"Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is elegant. Much better than what I was trying to do.